# WPF TileBrush and DrawingContext.DrawRectangle -- relative to upper-left of rectangle?

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, brush, drawingbrush

When using [DrawingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.aspx).[DrawRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606813.aspx) with a [TileBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.aspx), I noticed that the top-left of the rectangle is not the top-left of the underlying image. This occurs with both a [DrawingBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingbrush.aspx) and an [ImageBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush.aspx) with the source as a [DrawingImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingimage.aspx). Is there a way to force `DrawRectangle` to always snap the underlying brush to the top-left corner? Here's a picture:

[image: An image of the brush alignment issues]

The two rectangles are using the same brush but are at different points on the screen. As you can see, the brush's origin is different (it seems the brush is continuous over a much larger area). Here's a minimal repro:

```
    private static readonly Brush _brush;

    static CustomControl()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/image.png", UriKind.Absolute);
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(uri);
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);
        ImageDrawing drawing = new ImageDrawing(img, rect);
        _brush = new DrawingBrush
        {
            Drawing = drawing, 
            Viewport = rect,
            ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute,
            TileMode = TileMode.Tile 
        };
        _brush.Freeze();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        dc.DrawRectangle(_brush, null, new Rect(70, 70, 100, 150));
        dc.DrawRectangle(_brush, null, new Rect(200, 200, 80, 120));
    }
```

<sub>* In *this* case an ImageBrush would give the correct results, but in my program, I'm dealing with a DrawingBrush with a custom [GeometryDrawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometrydrawing.aspx).</sub>

I've tried using a pen instead of a brush, changing the TileMode, setting the stretch to Uniform, changing AlignmentX and AlignmentY... nothing seems to work. The origin of the brush is never set to the origin of the rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I used was to render it at (0,0) with a [TranslateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform.aspx). So instead of...

```
dc.DrawRectangle(_brush, null, new Rect(70, 70, 100, 150));
```

You can use:

```
TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform(70, 70);
transform.Freeze();
dc.PushTransform(transform);
dc.DrawRectangle(_brush, null, new Rect(0, 0, 100, 150));
dc.Pop();
```

This isn't ideal, since you have to allocate a new `TranslateTransform` (and therefore another underlying DUCE resource) every time you draw a new rectangle, but it performs well enough in my tests.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** You may still encounter some strange (but subtle) distortions on re-rendering, such as when scrolling. These might be caused by the subpixel rendering system. You can either play around with [GuidelineSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.guidelineset.aspx)s or just round the start point's X and Y to the nearest integer value.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, tiling brushes is very dependent on the relation between `Viewbox`, `ViewboxUnits`, `Viewport` and `ViewportUnits` properties of the brush.

Both properties for the units should be set to `Absolute`; the `Viewport` and `Viewbox` should be the same size (99% of the cases).

To elaborate, this is not something "official" that I've read, it's only from (a lot of) observation: the `Viewbox` is the size considered for rendering the drawing. If it's not set, the `Data` of the path will determine the `Viewbox` size. On the other hand, `Viewport` is the size considered while tiling the brush.

Setting the `Viewbox` to smaller size than `Viewport` will introduce spacing between each of the 'tiles' of the brush. Setting the `Viewbox` larger than `Viewport` will cause the 'tiles' to overlap (logically, on the screen the 'tile' will seem to be cut).

Comment: I've tried setting Viewbox and Viewport, just Viewbox, and just Viewport. The same behavior occurs in each case. The problem isn't with how the brush is tiling; it's with how it is rendering.